# Getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys' in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

This is a part of my whole code, where I am getting Typerror. This is what I did.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.plot(data.groupby(['Country']).groups.keys(), data.groupby(['Country'])['CustomerID'].count())
plt.xticks(rotation = 90, fontsize = 14)
plt.title("Number of transanctions done for each country")
plt.ylabel("No. of trans.")
plt.xlabel("Country")
plt.show()
```

Can't figure out how to solve this error.

Comment: Post full error traceback

Comment: Try `tuple(data.groupby(['Country']).groups.keys())` instead of `data.groupby(['Country']).groups.keys()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, dictionary should be passed as list

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.plot(list(data.groupby(['Country']).groups.keys()), list(data.groupby(['Country'])['CustomerID'].count()))
plt.xticks(rotation = 90, fontsize = 14)
plt.title("Number of transanctions done for each country")
plt.ylabel("No. of trans.")
plt.xlabel("Country")
plt.show()
```